# Warning Messages about Compat.jl in IJulia Jupyter

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook

I am getting these warning messages when running some code snippets in a Jupyter notebook with the Julia 0.4.3 kernel.

```
WARNING: Method definition readuntil(AbstractString, Any...) in module Compat at /home/bryan/.julia/v0.4/Compat/src/Compat.jl:807 overwritten in module Compat at /home/bryan/.julia/v0.4/Compat/src/Compat.jl:807.
WARNING: Method definition remote_do(Function, Main.Base.LocalProcess, Any...) in module Compat at /home/bryan/.julia/v0.4/Compat/src/Compat.jl:741 overwritten in module Compat at /home/bryan/.julia/v0.4/Compat/src/Compat.jl:741.
WARNING: Method definition remote_do(Function, Main.Base.Worker, Any...) in module Compat at /home/bryan/.julia/v0.4/Compat/src/Compat.jl:742 overwritten in module Compat at /home/bryan/.julia/v0.4/Compat/src/Compat.jl:742.
```

(Cut it short, lmk if you need more)

I think if I remove Compat.jl these messages might go away.  Is it safe to do this?

Comment: Can you share the code snippets you're attempting to run? I'm curious about how this presents itself. Sorry I can't tell you if it is safe to remove `Compat.jl`

Comment: @DanielArndt Let me see if I can narrow it down to one of the modules.

Answer (score 2):

Given that `Compat.jl` is the most depended on package in the entire ecosystem, removing `Compat` will end up removing most of your packages. Method definition overridden warnings are mostly harmless and can typically be ignored.

You could consider [Suppressor.jl](https://github.com/Ismael-VC/Suppressor.jl) to suppress them entirely.

Comment: I too get a bunch of these every time I load my modules, with ``0.5.2``.  They may be harmless, but they sure do fill up the console. An example of how to use ``Suppressor.jl`` would be useful. Is it just a case of wrapping whatever you're doing with ``@suppress begin ... end``?  The doc is not for newbies.

Comment: @PatrickT I will add more user friendly documentation to Suppressor, but yes, that is how you use it, you annotate the expression you want to suppress from (in julia everything is an expression).